# Split amount pro rata monthly

Tags: r, date, time, datatable, reshape

Hi ladies and gentlemen,
here you see my input file:

```
Input <- data.table(
  id = c("x1","x2","x3"),
  from = c("2020-01-01","2020-02-15","2019-01-15"), 
  to = c("2020-12-31","2021-02-14","2021-02-14"), 
  Amount = c(120, 120, 240) 
)
```

basically I would like to split the amount on a monthly basis. Can you suggest a fast and elegant way to do it?

Here what I would like to get for one of the id (for the other id the logic should be the same).

```
Output_x2 <- data.table(
  id = c("x2"),
  Period = c(2021), 
  to = c(202002, 202003, 202004, 202005, 202006, 202007, 202008, 202009, 202010, 202011, 202012, 202101, 202102), 
  Amount_ProRata = c(5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,5) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

spread <- function(x,y,z,value)
{
  nMonths <- as.duration(y %--% z) %>% 
    as.numeric("months") %>% 
    round(0)
  
  frac1 <- y %>% 
    {day(.)/days_in_month(.)} %>% 
    round(1)
  
  frac2 <- z %>% 
    {day(.)/days_in_month(.)} %>% 
    round(1)
  
  wholem <- round(nMonths - frac1 - frac2,0)
 
  splita <- (value/nMonths) * c(frac1,rep(1,wholem),frac2)
  splita <- splita[splita > 0]
    
  months <- seq(ymd(y),ymd(z)+2, by = "months")
  months <- months[1:length(splita)]
  
  df <- data.frame(id=x,
                   Period=year(months),
                   to=paste0(year(months),sprintf("%02d",month(months))),
                   Amount_ProRata=splita)
}

map_dfr(1:nrow(Input),
         ~ spread(Input$id[.x], Input$from[.x], Input$to[.x], Input$Amount[.x]))
```